# Timer inside while loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, timer

How would I go about implementing a timer inside a while loop like so in Java?

```
while (game not ended) {
//do something
(wait 5 seconds)
}
```

Would it be something like so?: (`java.util.Timer`)

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

    while (game not ended) {
        //do something
        new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your goal?

Comment: Search for "[java] game event loop". A Timer in Java is an *asynchronous* event source and not suitable for a game loop - but it may also be the case that the game should be written in an asynchronous style. (What *kind* of game is it? What does the *existing* game event loop look like? Is it using Swing for the UI?)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Its for a swing tetris game using AI. An agent solves for most efficient moves for a buffer of pieces. I want each move to be played in the gui for a set time so the marker can see each move as it is played... without delay you only see the last move.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with it? @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Java Thread.sleep() is a Pop Favorite:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Thread` class `static` [sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) method.

```
while (game not ended) {
   //do something
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```